# Some questions on the proof of Poincare inequality.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading POincare inequality from Evans ( can be found here : http://anhngq.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/the-poincare-inequality/ ) and i am having some trouble understanding it .
I would be glad if someone could explain the renormalizing step ? Specially i didn't understand how average of $v_k=0$ and few steps there .

I am also interested to know under what conditions does Poincare inequality hold ? Suppose if i take a constant function then it doesn't hold .

Thank you

Comment: Oh ok , i think i have got the answer to the the first question . if $\bar u$ is the mean of u and $v_k$ is the mean of $u-\bar u$ then the $v_k=0$

Answer (score 2):

See the book ["*Applied Functional Analysis*"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387944427) by Zeidler on p. 136. Maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that if a function $u$ is constant (ie. $\nabla u=0 $) and is also in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, then the function must be equal to zero *almost everywhere* (actually *everywhere* if we take its continuous representative, if we are consistent with the notation of Brezi's Book) in order to satisfy the boundary conditions. (By a well known theorem in fact the closure of the space of differentailble functions in the sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, that we denote by $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, is nothing but the functions in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ that are equal to zero on the boundary $\partial \Omega$)

Then

$\|u\|_{L^{p}(\Omega )}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^{p}(\Omega )},$

becomes the equality $0=C\cdot 0$ where the constant $C$ is not relevant

That's it